# type String is not a member of package scala.scalajs.js

Tags: scala.js

I just upgraded from version 0.5.6 to 0.6.3 of the Scala js and now some of my code no longer compiles. I have defined the following object:

```
trait Call extends js.Object {
    val name: js.String = ???
    val params: js.Dictionary[String] = ??? 
}
```

Which gives me the following compiler error:

> type String is not a member of package scala.scalajs.js

Should I just use the standard String?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should use the standard `String`.

Similarly, replace `js.Boolean` by `Boolean`, `js.Number` by `Double`, and `js.Undefined` by `Unit`.

See also [the type correspondence table](http://www.scala-js.org/doc/js-interoperability.html) in the documentation.